# macOS update failed, can't boot into macOS anymore

Tags: boot, mac

I tried to update macOS Mojave to Catalina. The update seems to have failed and messed up the boot loader

When I start with option pressed, I can only select the bootcamp partition and two drives that are just called EFI. They all start windows though.

```
bless --info
```

Shows

```
... Blessed System File is .../com.apple.installer/boot.efi
... Blessed System Folder is .../com.apple.installer
```

(... omitted by me). I can't change the startup disk to macOS though, it fails with:

```
Running bless to place boot files failed
```

the system.log ends with

```
Installer Progress: Status is "Restarting"
...
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system: committing to system shutdown
assertion failed: 18A391: launchd + 142080 ...: 0x16
```

How can I fix this, or get more information on what happened?

Output of `diskutil list` below:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         1.6 TB     disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                351.2 GB   disk1s3
   4:           Windows Recovery                         471.9 MB   disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.8 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            1.7 TB     disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 111.4 MB   disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.4 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk3s4

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Splasher                2.0 TB     disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk5

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk20

/dev/disk21 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk21

/dev/disk22 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk22

/dev/disk23 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk23
```

Comment: The bless command is useless when it comes to APFS booting.

Comment: @DavidAnderson as a way to fix it or useless in the boot process? To me it looks like it is stuck in the update, pointing to .../com.apple.installer/boot.efi

Comment: It looks to me that you have run out of space in the APFS container. From your posted output, `disk3` is 1.8 TB in size, but this is composed of `disk0s2` and `disk1s2`. The sum of these two is 1.72111 TB which probably means the displayed size of `disk3` was rounded up to get to 1.8 TB. The "Macintosh HD" volume (`disk3s1`) is 1.7 TB which *could* mean you are out of space. So, if you did get the installer up and running again, the result would probably be another crash.

Comment: FYI, @Geoff Nixon pointed out in a comment to a different question that `systemsetup` is a replacement for the `bless` command. Some useful flags would be `-getstartupdisk`, `-liststartupdisks` and `-setstartupdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to reinstall macOS. To do that power off mac and power on, then click <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for reinstall current installed version of macOS or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> latest macOS compatible with your Mac just after power on and click it until Apple logo appears.

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn’t show the system partition as boot option

Comment: Did you tried to fix disk with Disk Utility? If you can enter into Recovery mode then enter to Disk utility and try to fix disk. Here is a detailed guide: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/08/repair-boot-disk-mac-os-x-disk-utilit/

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what your original version was, and of course what exactly went wrong, you may have a snapshot available that you can restore to on the boot volume.

If you don’t already have a backup on an external drive/NAS/cloud of all the information from the computer you care about keeping, I’d suggest get macOS running on a external hard drive and use that to browse and copy everything you need first, since if you get a snapshot to start restoring and then it fails, it will probably be MUCH harder to recover data afterwards.

Boot to recovery (⌘+R) or internet recovery (Option+⌘+R), and then choose the option to restore from Time Machine.
If “Macintosh HD” or whatever you had previously named your startup volume if there as a option to restore from, then it should have a snapshot of your system from immediately prior to the attempted update, so you can get booting again.

I don’t know if this will leave the install logs intact for you to review however, but if successful then at least you’ll have a booting macOS, and you can make a time machine backup if you don’t already have one, and then if you have to do a re-partition and clean install to get the update going, you can get everything set up more quickly from the backup

[About Time Machine Local Snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015)

Comment: -1: This really doesn’t add anything new to a question about a system that was borked up about 4 years ago and already has a more succinct answer posted.

Comment: Oh apologies, I didn’t notice the dates. Wonder why this popped up in my feed

Comment: The automated “Community” user routinely promotes older questions that might not have an official answer selected to give it more attention. That sometimes (in my humble option, more often than not) results in questions that don’t need promotion getting promoted. Like this one!

Comment: Ahhhh I did not know that. I’ll keep a better eye on dates in future just in case. Thanks for the explainer!